# Make model class into List

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to have 2 data responses for 2 api endpoints. 1 is a single response, and the other is an array of a single response.

When trying to create the `List/array` version, I get errors. What's the proper way to make the following model class into a List as well?

```
class SingleDataResponse {
  final String id;
  final String title;

  SingleDataResponse({
    this.id,
    this.title
  });

  factory SingleDataResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SingleDataResponse(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title']
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;

    return data;
  }
}
```

Here's what I'm expecting to get in the `List` Model:

```
[{_id: "5f210afa8215ff24307c6c53", title: "Cool Title"}]
```

Comment: can you post a sample json response.

Comment: @SagarAcharya Updated question to include the json response I'm expecting to get.

Comment: Can you try changing your `Map<String, dynamic>` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` and `return [data]` and see if that you want @Jessica ?

Comment: @Alok I want to return 2 separate classes though...

Answer (score 0):

just check out the example that I have created does this answer your question let me know.

This is the single object json

```
{
    "_id": "5f210afa8215ff24307c6c53",
    "title": "Cool Title"
}
```

This is the list of object:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f210afa8215ff24307c6c53",
        "title": "Cool Title"
    }
]
```

And this is the model class for the it I have taken the json locally.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do

import 'dart:convert';
// this is for single object
//     final dataModel = singledataModelFromJson(jsonString);

DataModel singledataModelFromJson(String str) =>
    DataModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String singledataModelToJson(DataModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

// this is for list of objects.
//     final dataModel = dataModelFromJson(jsonString);

List<DataModel> dataModelFromJson(String str) =>
    List<DataModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => DataModel.fromJson(x)));

String dataModelToJson(List<DataModel> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class DataModel {
  DataModel({
    this.id,
    this.title,
  });

  String id;
  String title;

  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataModel(
        id: json["_id"],
        title: json["title"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "title": title,
      };
}
```

This is the logic in main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_parsing_example/models.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  double value;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata();
  }

  getdata() async {
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    final singledataModel = singledataModelFromJson(data);
    print('single model');
    print(singledataModel.id);
    print(singledataModel.title);

    String listdata =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse2.json");

    List<DataModel> dataModel = dataModelFromJson(listdata);
    print(dataModel.length);
    print(dataModel[0].title);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Text(''));
  }
}
```

Just check it and let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: How can I make the List version a class as well?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want. because I am not getting you for the list version.

Comment: Like in my example, the way to access `fromJson` is by doing `SingleDataResponse.fromJson`. I want the List to be like that as well